# How to click a hyperlink(<a> tag) automatically by clicking only a submit button in html?

Tags: php, html, laravel-5

```
<input type='submit' name='btnAdd'  onclick="{{ route('eventCal_index', $_SESSION['title']) }}" value='Add event' >
```

Submit button should be both work for submission and navigate to that route

That means without clicking the hyperlink, by clicking the submit button I want to click another link automatically. Simply, Is there a way to click a hyperlink(`<a>` tag) automatically

Comment: Why do need to click the hyperlink as well?

Comment: You should do it in other way , just submit your data and then from php side redirect

Comment: After the submission of data how to click the hyperlink as well?

Comment: I need to click the hyperlink as well because it shouldn't be another seperate action as it is not user friendly.

Comment: @M.David — As Armen said, the server should redirect after the form submission is complete. That's still only one activity for the user. If, OTOH, you want to follow the link then you would have to cancel the form submission because both activities load new pages.

Answer (score 0):

In the route function at the end of it add

```
$("#linkid").trigger('click');
```

Please see this page for more details:-http://www.w3schools.com/JQuery/event_trigger.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try this
//on submission of form ,you can trigger click event.

```
$('form').on('submit',function()      
{
    $('a').trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: While this maybe can answer the question, it's better to provide some explanations about how this code help.